# Angular8 routing empty or parameterized

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router

In a child module (path "invoice") I'm trying to register the following routes:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: SearchComponent
},
{
    path: ':quotationNumber',
    component: InvoiceComponent
}
];
```

The idea is that "/invoice" shows the SearchComponent while "/invoice/any" shows the InvoiceComponent, passing "any" as parameter "quotationNumber". But as soon as the second route is added it always is chosen! "/invoice" also loads the InvoiceComponent with an empty parameter.

Setting

```
{
   path: '',
   component: SearchComponent,
   pathMatch:'full'
}
```

does not change the behavior.

**Edit:**
Actually the scenario is a bit different - maybe this causes the issues?

AppModule loads CustomerModule:

```
{
    path: 'customer',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customer/customer.module').then(mod => mod.CustomerModule)
},
```

CustomerModule loads InvoiceModule:

```
{
    path: 'invoice',
    loadChildren: () => import('./invoice/invoice.module').then(mod => mod.InvoiceModule)
},
```

and the InvoiceModule loads the module with the components as described.

The full path actually is

- /customer/invoice
- /customer/invoice/any

"Any" **always** get loaded! But I've noticed that calling "/customer/invoice" calls the InvoiceComponent (route "/customer/invoice/:param") with param "invoice"! It looks like the 2nd module does not remove "invoice" from the url when passing to its children.

**EDIT EDIT**: I found the mistake: the 2nd module **imported** the 3rd one, too. That caused its routes to get loaded as current and not as child. 2nd answer is for a correct setup correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pathMatch` field for empty path:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: SearchComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full',
},
```

Comment: As I've already written this did not change the behavior. _Should_ it work? What else could block it from working?

Comment: Furthermore this could only be a solution if the first route (with the SearchComponent) was **always** shown. My problem is that it gets **never** shown! The route ":quotationNumber" also matches the empty path ("/invoice").

Answer (score 0):

replace routes object with

```
  const routes: Routes = [{
        path: "invoice/:quotationNumber",
        children: [
          {
            path: "**",
            component: InvoiceComponent
          }
        ]},
       {
        path: "/invoice",
        component: SearchComponent

      }]
```

Comment: This is not possible since my modules does not control the path "invoice" - the AppModule loads the InvoiceModule as "invoice":

{
        path: 'invoice',
        loadChildren: () => import('./invoice/invoice.module').then(mod => mod.InvoiceModule)
    },